# Cheap wire tracer for house wiring

Tags: electrical

There a lot of inexpensive (<$20) tracers such as [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B093JQJTP3) available online. All of them I've seen are indicated for use for low voltage wiring only. I'm assuming the concern is that the internals of the tracer are not rated to handle line voltage and will get fried if that gets fed in. (In the worst case, potentially causing the unit in my hand to fail in a spectacularly dangerous way.)

If I am confident that none of the wires are live (e.g., the breaker to the whole house is off) is there any reason such a tracer can't be used to effectively test continuity?

I'm not looking for a product recommendation. I'm asking whether wire tracers designed for telecommunications can be reasonably expected to work with household wiring. I have an odd switch configuration that I'm trying to trace back to the box.

Comment: Yes you could, you stil have to keep in mind that different loads on the line such as bulbs, tvs, fridges may affect your results. What problem are you trying to solve.

Comment: I'm not looking for a product recommendation. I'm just asking generically if wire tracers designed for telecommunications cables can be expected to function well for house wiring.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelMior this is not a product recommendation question. It is a "can this kind of tool be used for this job" question, very DIY. Voted to re-open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Continuity testing" is checking if a wire is complete from one end to the other. You will have to know where the other end of the wire is, or test all the wires to find the end of the one you're starting to test.

Be absolutely confident that you have turned off all power at the main breaker/cut-off, including battery backup, auto-start generators, solar, wind, basement fusion reactor, antimatter source, dark matter wormhole etc.

Be sure the property isn't fed by more than one power source.

Unplug all devices on the outlets and turn off the lights so you don't get crosstalk, then the linked device may work for continuity testing, or at least tone-finding a wire or cable.

However, a standard volt/ohmmeter can also work for continuity testing and may be more useful than a specialized tool. Since it can do volts too, it can be used to check if the circuit is de-energized before ohm-continuity testing.

Comment: And if you want to actually trace the location of wires as they run through the building, there are devices for that too but they cost an order of magnitude more. I have sometimes been able to use the breaker-finder for that purpose, but that only works if the circuit is live and I was trying to find where a contractor had cut through a wire.

Comment: @Triplefault Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm aware of what continuity testing is and I already have a voltmeter. The two locations are just sufficiently separated that it's inconvenient to run a lead between them.

Comment: You can get some other known wire, temporarily connected and running along the hallway, to serve as a return for the continuity test. An audio feedback may be useful, but as @MTA pointed out, the results may not be reliable.

Comment: Contactless hot-wire tester also exists. I would really use that before touching AC. It's a habit that might just save your life.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to make a map to show which outlets are served by which breakers.

I have a phone line tracer similar to the one you indicated, and while it works great for phone lines or ethernet, it **does not** work well for house wiring in my experience. That's why I ended up buying a Klein Tools model made for house wiring similar to the one Triplefault mentions, but an earlier model. That worked great and saved a lot of time. (No affiliation.)

You can get through the project most efficiently if you first make a map of the house showing all outlets and light fixtures, and then have a helper with a phone go through the house room-by-room, plugging the transmitter into each outlet in turn while you scan the breakers and announce the breaker number for your helper to write on the map. The scanning device beeps when you pass it over the breaker that's feeding the outlet with the transmitter.

For light fixtures, use a screw-in adapter and do the same.

All that leaves is built-ins like dishwashers, electric range, etc., but those may already be labeled on the service panel.

Comment: I'm not trying to map breakers. I already have a device specifically for that purpose. I have a light fixture that's not currently functioning and I'm trying to figure out which wires from a nearby box are feeding it.

Comment: @MichaelMior The phone tracer may work OK over that short a distance, but it works best on twisted pairs, which is not what you have in the wall. Just be aware that you'll get crosstalk between adjacent conductors and likely a signal on more than one wire. You'll have to judge which wire is beeping the loudest. An ohmmeter would be a better choice unless you don't have the electrical chops to interpret the results.